# 20.04 with mdadm and lvm hangs on shutdown

Tags: shutdown, raid, freeze, lvm

I have a server set up on 20.04 with two mdadm raids and lvm volumes put on top of those raid setups for `/home` on the first raid device and then `/`, `/var` and `/tmp` on the second raid device.

Any time I run a shutdown, reboot, poweroff or similar operation, the system runs through most of the shutdown sequence (including stopping the persistence of journal and shutdown logs) and then hangs after `Shutdown[1]: Rebooting` or `Shutdown[1]: Powering Off`.  If I hit ESC, it appears to show that the unmounts of `/var` `/tmp` and `/` are failing, causing the raid device to fail to shutdown, though I don't know if this is causing the hang or if it's merely a coincidental, separate issue.  Pictures are attached below.

I have only the intel integrated graphics and have checked the usual driver culprits.  I also have updated the bios and tried various settings of acpi in grub as suggested in other answers.

What else should I be checking/providing here in order to hunt this down?

[Power Off First Half](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xuzzs.jpg)

[Power Off Second Half](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8x56B.jpg)

Comment: Anyone have any thoughts of even just what other logging is needed or what else I should try?  I don't want to just open this as a bug and assume there's something else I can be providing here to help track things down.